# Snakeyaml Yaml.load() does not raise error for duplicate keys

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am loading my yaml contents using snakeyaml's `yaml.load(yamlContents)` function.

Yaml contents has duplicate keys present in it. 
eg :

```
 parameters:
   param1 : value1
   param2 : value2
   param1 : value3
```

Yaml on load will give a LinkedHashMap with two keys `param1` and `param2`, with values `value3` and `value2` respectively.

I want to raise an exception/flag saying `Invalid contents, duplicate key(param1) found on line 4`.

Please guide me on how to do this. Also, examples given are out of mind. Please be lenient in case there are issues in them.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [`LoaderOptions` class](https://static.javadoc.io/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.20/org/yaml/snakeyaml/LoaderOptions.html).  You can supply a `LoaderOptions` to your [`Yaml` object](https://static.javadoc.io/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.20/org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml.html#Yaml-org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor-org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer-org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions-org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions-org.yaml.snakeyaml.resolver.Resolver-).